# Email or username validation

Tags: java, spring

I want to check the email from database through controller and check if the email already exists or not!!! (email = column in db), please suggest me some ideas i'm new here

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {

    if (!user.getName().isEmpty() || !user.getEmail().isEmpty() || !user.getPassword().isEmpty()) {

        user.setPassword(DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(user.getPassword().getBytes()));

        udao.addUser(user);
        return "login";
        }

        else {
        model.addAttribute("error", "fill the form completely!!!");
        return "signup";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the udao as your data access, you just need to create a method that gets the user object given an email id like

```
@Query(value="select * from users where email = :emailId and isactive=1", nativeQuery=true)
User getUserByEmailId(@Param("emailId")String emailId);
```

**OR**

```
@Query(value="select count(*) from users where email = :emailId and isactive=1", nativeQuery=true)
Integer getUserByEmailId(@Param("emailId")String emailId);
```

In the option2, you just get the count of the users having the email, a value of `0` indicates that the email is `Unique` and otherwise.

Once this DAO is completed, you can verify by calling this method and if your response is null, it means that there is no user in the db, else user is present, you can show the end user that the user already exists with the provided email id.

Couple of points for improving the code,
Please do not write your `DAO` accessing logic in the controller, it is best advised to use a service like `UserDetailsService` so that all the data access and business rules are applied in the service facilitating SOC, UnitTestability and lot more.

Also, consider using a highly secure algorithm for handling passwords like `PBKDF2` which is very secure.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using Spring Data JPA you can query the DB in order to check if there is an user with that email, by [Spring Data JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) (check the ***Example 60. Query method declaration in UserRepository***):

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
  User findByEmail(String emailAddress);
}
```

So, in your controller you can do something like:

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) {

    if (!user.getName().isEmpty() || !user.getEmail().isEmpty() || !user.getPassword().isEmpty()) {

        User userFromDb = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

        // Please note that I'm not sure if it will return null or empty User object, you need to check that
        if (userFromDb == null) {
            // Do the logic if no email exists in the DB
        } else {
            // Do the logic if an email exists in the DB
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually i want to address the path of email like(@PathVariable("email") String email) column in db inside the controller and check the input there only and pass it to the database if there does not exists a similar email...